# Android programmatically added button has match parent width and height

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add this button

```
        Button dalsi_akce = new Button(this);
        dalsi_akce.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dalsi_akce.setLayoutParams(p);
        setContentView(dalsi_akce);
        dalsi_akce.setText("test");
```

button appears but is full match parent. I have this button over whole display. How to set width and height of button?

Comment: setContentView(dalsi_akce); What are you trying to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the activity's content to be a button. That's why it spans over the whole activity and is simply wrong.

Instead create your activity's layout (an xml file) and set it with `setContentView`. Then you can programatically add a button to the content.

Example:

**your activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    Button dalsi_akce = new Button(this);
    dalsi_akce.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dalsi_akce.setLayoutParams(p);
    dalsi_akce.setText("test");


    viewGroup.addView(dalsi_akce);
}
```

**main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. You help me realize how works setContentView and addView. You solved my problem and teach me some new things.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should define your content view as a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout, then add your button to this layout. Also You can another constructor of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams class:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 70);
```

actually you use this constructor :

```
public LayoutParams(int w, int h) {
    super(w, h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you just created your layout in layout.xml, and then customize your buttons as you wish in code. For example you could do the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Button
  android:id"@+id/left_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:text="Left"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This would give you one button that is only as big as its contents in the top right corner.